# More than one EndPoint on USB using PIC16F1455/1459

Tags: usb, pic

I am using a PIC16F1455 to collect data and send to a computer.

I used existing code for simple testing, which uses one end point only. Szymons code is my base, which I have expanded a bit.
I would like to use 3 endpoints for my application.

I have tried to set up the system to have 2 endpoints, but my second endpoint is not working.

I can add that

- I have my configuration descriptor as below
- The host will ask for Report Descriptor 1, but not for the 2nd one
- when trying to send something from Endpoint 2, I can only see that UEP2 is owned by the SIE (Serial Interface Engine)
- When I try to alter code so UEP1 should use UEP2 hardware, then it does not work. I did this by changing addresses from 01 to 02 and 81 to 82. Doing this with just one will make it work one way only.
- Below my code, which I had with 2 endpoints, which gave no error. Just UEP2 does not work. Missing up interface count and message size will give an error. The comments will tell what changes can be done

I guess that if but channels should be the same, then the same configurations for both end points should be fine, only the endpoint number and addresses need change. Am I right?

I also understand, that UEP0 is used by the system and cannot be used for custom messages.

I need some ideas what could be wrong - how to get a second end point to work. I am out of ideas and I find it hard to google much on this. It should ask for both reports when using 2 end points, right?

```
// Configuration descriptor
const ConfigStruct ConfigurationDescriptor =
{
    {
        // Configuration descriptor
    0x09,   // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    0x02,   // CONFIGURATION descriptor type
    0x29,   // Total length of data for this cfg LSB  // was 29 // 49 for 2 end points
    0x00,   // Total length of data for this cfg MSB
    1,//INTF,   // Number of interfaces in this cfg
    0x01,   // Index value of this configuration
    SCON,   // Configuration string index
    0xA0,   // Attributes (USB powered, wake-up))
    0x32,   // Max power consumption (in 2 mA steps)
    },
    {
        // Generic HID Interface descriptor
    0x09,   // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    0x04,   // INTERFACE descriptor type
    IHID,   // Interface Number       //<- I assume that it stays 1 just using UEP2. Cannot start from 2
    0x00,   // Alternate Setting Number
    0x02,   // Number of endpoints in this interface
    0x03,   // Class code (HID)
    0x00,   // Subclass code
    0x00,   // Protocol code 0-none, 1-Keyboard, 2- Mouse
    0x00,   // Interface string index

        // Generic Hid Class-Specific descriptor
    0x09,   // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    0x21,   // HID descriptor type
    0x11,   // HID Spec Release Number in BCD format (1.11) LSB
    0x01,   // HID Spec Release Number in BCD format (1.11) MSB
    0x00,   // Country Code (0x00 for Not supported)
    0x01,   // Number of class descriptors
    0x22,   // Report descriptor type
    0x2F,   // Report Size LSB  (47 bytes)
    0x00,   // Report Size MSB

        // Generic HID Endpoint 1 In
    0x07,   // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    0x05,   // ENDPOINT descriptor type
    0x81,   // Endpoint Address     //<----- changing to 82 will not work
    0x03,   // Attributes (Interrupt)
    HRBC,   // Max Packet Size LSB
    0x00,   // Max Packet Size MSB
    0x01,   // Interval (1 millisecond)

        // Generic HID Endpoint 1 Out
    0x07,   // Size of this descriptor in bytes
    0x05,   // ENDPOINT descriptor type
    0x01,   // Endpoint Address  //<--------changing on 02 will not work
    0x03,   // Attributes (Interrupt)
    HRBC,   // Max Packet Size LSB
    0x00,   // Max Packet Size MSB
    0x01,   // Interval (1 millisecond)
```

Comment: Don't know anything about this but one of the things that stands out is number of interfaces in this config.  Should that be 2?

Comment: @cup mar, I would change this among other values when needed. If this number is incorrect, the hole thing will fail

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake to be in the reply of reports - or descriptors. It would only allow to reply for endpoint 0 (endpoint 1 in hw), meaning when the host would ask for next descriptor, it would not get answer.

```
  if((SetupPacket.bmRequestType & 0x1F) != 0x01 || (SetupPacket.wIndex0 != 0x00)) return;
```

needs to be

```
if((SetupPacket.bmRequestType & 0x1F) != 0x01 || (SetupPacket.wIndex0 > (InterfaceCount - 1))) return;
```

Then it works
Next step is that in PC host side, every end point is a connection by itself